# How do I modularize polyfills in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have various polyfills/shims I would like to use in my AngularJS app.

For example, `classList` is not supported in IE9 and below.

I've tried two ways of defining polyfills in my app:

First, by simply placing all polyfills at the top of my `app.js` page, wherein all other modules are defined and configured.

Second, I've tried this:

```
angular.module('polyfills',[]);
angular.module('polyfills')
    .config([function() {
        // all polyfills in here
    }]);
```

Both options work. However, both options seem a little weird to me. Intuitively, using `.config` feels like I should be sticking to configuring things like providers, interceptors, etc. It seems like this might be an issue that has already been resolved in the past, and I have the feeling some sort of best practice has come about as a result.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: you would be running polyfills pretty late in the page loading cycle doing it this way

Comment: @charlietfl, what do you mean? What concerns would this present?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just add it as a normal script to your page?  jquery is often used with angularjs but you don't try and put it in a module.  You just drop a script tag pointing to jquery just like you do with angular.  Polyfills are more like jquery in this regard.

Comment: @chubbsondubs but what about other functions that have no "module" to live in? jQuery is a library, polyfills are basically lambda functions.
I agree with OP- I'm curious if there's a better way. I just tried taking an arrayContains() function out of a module and then realized that that module is entirely dependent on knowing about and being able to access it. If that external file were not included, developers would be required to guess on how it works, which creates huge risk for breakages. Unfortunately numerous modules use it, so abstracting it to a higher level is actually a good idea.

Comment: @JoshBeam how about a service? That's the only thing I can think of that would be non-global and an integral part of the application that would be manageable in one place. I think I'm going to take that route; then I can do something like PolfillsService.arrayContains()...
 Still feels weird, though.

Comment: @dudewad, thanks for the input. Yeah that sounds like something that could work. I guess that method is portable between Angular apps (for example, if you create a module that exposes that PolyfillService, you can drop it into theoretically any Angular app), but obviously it does have the downside of being directly coupled to the Angular architecture.

Comment: True, but I would write it as discreet method calls that you could take elsewhere. Typically when bootstrapping a project (e.g. setting up grunt/bower/whatever FE tools you use) I am including and picking/choosing polyfills anyways. I'm not a big fan of "including all polyfills just in case". It might even be cool to run/maintain a git repo that supports multiple polyfill settings, e.g. a native JS set and an angular service, etc. Perhaps a pull-only origin could augment an existing site architecture for updates to a given polyfill set. But now I'm getting all complex.

Comment: @dudewad, yeah makes sense.

Comment: Still you are running the actual polyfill after Angular has had a chance to boot up.  So your polyfills aren't available to any other script you might be including until Angular is done running.  So the browser doesn't support these features, then sometime later all of a sudden does.  I don't know what you are actually trying to solve by trying to wrap these in Angular architecture.  Sounds like over engineering to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't put your polyfills in an angular module, that's weird and not what you want.  What you want is for the js implementation in each browser to look the same, so load your polyfills before any other js resource.  Create a js file (or more if you want each polyfill in its own file) that contains your polyfill(s) and is loaded in a script tag before any of your other js files.  Your polyfills should also be inside IIFE's.

Here's what an example polyfill for Array.from (this is a very simple polyfill for demo purposes):

array-from-polyfill.js

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  Object.defineProperty(Array, 'from', {
    configurable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    value: function (object) {
        'use strict';
        return [].slice.call(object);
    }
    });
})();
```

Then put the following tag in your index.html (or whatever you call your top level template) *before* any other js files.  Yes, even before angular or bootstrap resources.

```
<script src="path/to/array-from-polyfill.js"></script>
```

Two last items of note.  First, always use Object.defineProperty, and set 'enumerable' to false.  That is unless you want certain ways of iterating over an object's properties to pick up your polyfills.  This means that you'll have to fiddle with MDN's polyfills, but that's fine.  You should probably know your way around defineProperty anyways.

Second, I suggest that you load your polyfills in every browser, even if the browser already has that function.  Basically, your executed code should be the same everywhere, as much as possible.  Nothing is more irritating that having a bug in one specific browser, because it is (or is not as the case may be) using your polyfill.  This isn't a universal truth, so do what feels right to you.

Don't forget to make sure that your polyfills are also loaded in your testing environment, and to regularly check if you can retire a polyfill.